# Distance and time of two boats?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A and B are two boats in a 200m race. A and B started at the same time but A finished 10m or 2 seconds before B. Calculate the speed of A and B.

Guys tell me how to solve this kind of problem...

Comment: By "A finished $10$m or $2$ seconds before B", I assume you mean A finished when B had $10$m left, then B finished $2$ seconds later?  And are we supposed to assume they both travel at constant speeds?

Comment: Nothing mentioned like constant speeds, this was the exact question asked to me on a interview.

Answer (score 1):

We are invited to assume that our two racers each race at constant speed. This is not true of real racing.

That A finished two seconds ahead means that B took an additional two seconds to finish. So B's speed is $5$. It therefore took B $38$ seconds to travel the $190$ metres. In that time, A trvaelled $200$ metres, so her speed was $\frac{200}{38}$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  Let $a$ be the speed of A and $b$ be the speed of B.  We are told that A covered 200m in the same time that B covered 190m, so $a=\frac{200}{190}b$.  We are also told that A was 2 sec ahead of B over 200m, so $\frac {200}a+2=\frac {200}b$.  Two equations, two unknowns.

Answer (score 0):

As given A finished 10m or 2sec before b
So B have to travel 10 m in 2 sec so B's speed is 5m/sec.
So total time taken by b to complete is 200/5=40 sec

As given A finish 2 sec before so A takes 38 sec to finish 
So A's speed is 200/38=100/19m/sec